# Is $H$ a subgroup of $\Gamma$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

The question is in the picture, I understand the requirements for a subset to be a subgroup (closure, associativity under the same operation etc.), however I am struggling with this question. I would be grateful if someone could walk me through this. Thanks in advance.

> **1.3.** Let $\Gamma$ denote the set of all mappings $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)\ne 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. For $f,g\in\Gamma$, define $fg$ by $$fg(x)=f(x)g(x)$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. You may assume that the set $\Gamma$ forms a group with respect to the above composition.
>
> Let $H$ be the subset of $\Gamma$ defined to be the set of all mappings $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}$. Is $H$ a subgroup of $\Gamma$? Remember to justify your answer fully.

Comment: Well, as you suggest, this comes down to checking all the properties a subgroup must have.  Just go one by one.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: When you were told not to use a picture, the implication was that it should be replaced with MathJax, not removed with no other changes. The edited question had absolutely no indication of what the question was actually about. I rolled back to the one with the picture, please consider typing it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constant mapping $h_2$ equal to $2$ belongs to $H$. Its inverse (namely the constant mapping equal to $1/2$) doesn't belong to $H$ though. So $H$ isn't a subgroup of $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subgroup criterion. We just need to check whether $e\in H$, and whether $x,y\in H\implies xy^{-1}\in H$.